# Puedo crear un componente que tenga dentro Routes?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

Holaaaa buenas tardes, espero que la esten pasando bien en estas navidades.

Tengo una duda sobre react-router-domv6 y es la siguiente:

```
function RouteMain() {
  return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<TOutlet />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/classi" element={<Classes />}>
          <Route index element={<ChoiceSchool />} />
          <Route path="/classi/:nameOfSchool" element={<ChoiceFieldOfStudy />}/>
          <Route path="/classi/:nameOfSchool/:fieldOfStudy" element={<ChoiceYear />}/>
          <Route path="/classi/:nameOfSchool/:fieldOfStudy/:year" element={<ChoiceSection/>}/>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
   </BrowserRouter>)}
```

Tengo esta funcion donde renderizo rutas para mi app, pero quisiera saber si puedo crear un componente para ordenar mi codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
function RouterMain() {
  return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<TOutlet />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <RouteSecond />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>)}

function RouteSecond() {
  return (
   <Route path="/classi" element={<Classes />}>
     <Route index element={<ChoiceSchool />} />
     <Route path="/classi/:nameOfSchool" element={<ChoiceFieldOfStudy />} />
     <Route path="/classi/:nameOfSchool/:fieldOfStudy" element={<ChoiceYear />}/>
   <Route path="/classi/:nameOfSchool/:fieldOfStudy/:year" element={<ChoiceSection />}/>
</Route>)}
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

Si alguien es tan amable de ayudame se lo agradeveria muchisimo!!!!!

Feliz navidaaaaaad :DDDD

Answer (score 1):

```
   function RouterMain() {
  return (
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<TOutlet />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <RouteSecond />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
  );
}

function RouteSecond() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/classi" element={<Classes />}>
        <Route index element={<ChoiceSchool />} />
        <Route path="/classi/:nameOfSchool" element={<ChoiceFieldOfStudy />} />
        <Route
          path="/classi/:nameOfSchool/:fieldOfStudy"
          element={<ChoiceYear />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/classi/:nameOfSchool/:fieldOfStudy/:year"
          element={<ChoiceSection />}
        />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
```

Comment: Creo que poniendo otro Routes y colocando el BrowserRouter en el index.js podría funcionarte.